# Problems with the same user session on simultaneous requests

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I was assigned to maintain the project that sells game item codes via the web app and deliver the codes via the text message to customer's mobiles. There is a problem that I still don't know how to solve it.

It simply occurs when the user purchases the product. They just click to puchase once but the app seems to process the purchasing stage for multiple times. So the users get a lot of items by paying for just one item.

Normally, the users have to add funds vi credit card to their accounts in order to have the sufficient balance to buy the product. So, this stage is conditional. Here is the brief code

```
<?php
    public function actionPurchase() {
        $user = Users::findOne(['mobile' => Yii::$app->session->get('mobile')]);

        $product_price = Yii::$app->session->get('product_price');

        $product_code = ProductStock::getCodefromPrice($product_price);

        // Save the transaction log
        $transaction = new Transactions();
        $transaction->product_code = $product_code;
        $transaction->amount = $product_price;
        $transaction->user_id = $user->id;
        $transaction->credit_before = $user->balance;
        $transaction->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $transaction->save();

        if ($user->balance >= $product_price) {

            // Redeem the product from the API
            $raw = ProductStock::redeem($product_code);

            // Decode the JSON response
            $response = json_decode($resp);
            if ($response->status == 'Success') {

                // Adjust the user balance
                $new_credit = $user->balance - $product_price;
                $user->balance = $new_credit;
                $user->update();

                // Send the SMS
                Utilities::sendSMS($user->mobile, $response->item_pin);

                return $this->redirect(['success']);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

As you can see that the I also record the transaction with user credit before and after the purchase. So if the purchase is success. I reduce the user balance from the user table and record the credit after to be the ducucted one.

Please note that the users are stored in the MySQL table along with their current balance. So, here is how the table looks like

```
| id |    mobile     | balance |       created        |
|  1 |   0811234567  |   300   |  2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
```

And the transaction table looks like this

```
|   id   | user_id  |  product_code | amount |  credit_before  |  credit_after  |        created         |
| 119687 |    1     |    estr1203   |  100   |       300       |    200         |   2017-01-01 13:15:02  |
```

Hence, if the users successfully purchase the product they will have their balance deducted at the end.

But this is the result from the problem I am current encountering

```
|   id   | user_id  |  product_code | amount |  credit_before  |  credit_after  |        created         |
| 119691 |    1     |    estr1203   |  100   |       200       |    100         |   2017-01-01 13:15:03  |
| 119690 |    1     |    estr1203   |  100   |       200       |    100         |   2017-01-01 13:15:03  |
| 119689 |    1     |    estr1203   |  100   |       300       |    200         |   2017-01-01 13:15:02  |
| 119688 |    1     |    estr1203   |  100   |       300       |    200         |   2017-01-01 13:15:02  |
| 119687 |    1     |    estr1203   |  100   |       300       |    200         |   2017-01-01 13:15:02  |
```

Please see the log creation time, they are the same. Normally, if the users click to purchase the product multiple times it will process the transaction multiple times too. So their balance should get deducted in sequence like 300 to 200 and the next time is 200 to 100 until they run out of balance and can no longer make a purhase. For the example above the correct transaction record should be

```
|   id   | user_id  |  product_code | amount |  credit_before  |  credit_after  |        created         |
| 119689 |    1     |    estr1203   |  100   |       100       |    0         |   2017-01-01 13:15:02  |
| 119688 |    1     |    estr1203   |  100   |       200       |    100         |   2017-01-01 13:15:02  |
| 119687 |    1     |    estr1203   |  100   |       300       |    200         |   2017-01-01 13:15:02  |
```

But this looks like the app treats these simultaneous requests as the same one because it is the same user and all access the the if condition to check whether the user has sufficient balance at the same time. So the multiple items are sent to the user and they just click to purchase once.

Anyone can give me good ideas of how to handle such a problem? I don't know how to solve it by now and have been working on it for already couple days. Could it be a problem from the gap when the app call the API for the item code to be sent to the user and when the simultaneous requests from the same user come. The user's balance is not yet deducted until the product is successfully returned from the API. So the balance checking condition returns true. I got no idea on it. Becaause when I test it, it works properly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First thing to do is to find out who is triggering `actionPurchase` many times ? . **OR** did it execute one time, but the function itself is broken(doing many purchases for the same call?). echo something at the first line of the function to see if it is triggered many times or not.

Comment: @Accountantم It is the user that clicks to trigger the actionPurchase method. I am not sure whether there is a trick to mimic the same request simultaneously but when I test it, it is triggered once and the balance get deducted in sequence. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Can't you just query the TransactionLog for the same transaction?